update with group column in the same table
I try to assign random value in ref column.
You can see my try in https://dbfiddle.uk/949fv4di
Result should be :



ref
prod




23
prodA


23
prodA


12
prodB


12
prodB


12
prodB


23
prodA


7
prodC


23
prodA


23
prodA


7
prodC




You can use a cte to assign a random value to each prod group and then use that value for the update:
with cte (rnd, prod) as (
  select CAST(trunc(RANDOM() * 100)  AS integer), prod 
  from ( select distinct prod from secto ) as t
)
update secto x
  set ref = rnd
from cte y
where x.prod = y.prod

Fiddle
AFAIK, update ... from is not part of SQL standard. Starting with postgres 15 you can use MERGE which were introduced in SQL:2003
merge into secto x
using (
  select CAST(trunc(RANDOM() * 100)  AS integer), prod 
  from ( select distinct prod from secto ) as t
) y (rnd, prod)
  on x.prod = y.prod
when matched then
  update set ref = y.rnd;

Fiddle 2
